# plugging in a microcontroller in an fpga board

Tags: microcontroller, fpga, development

so i'm about to buy this fpga board:

http://www.ebay.com/itm/Mojo-V3-FPGA-Developement-Board-Spartan-6-XC6SLX9-FPGA-/200967239091

it has the spartan 6 i'm looking for and it comes with a microcontroller. but this thing having it's own microontroller got me wondering...

can an fpga board without a microcontroller just have a external microcontroller plugged into it (through the pins, say) and work almost identically as if it was an fpga board with a built-in microcontroller??

Comment: Related: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/86126/2028

Answer (score 2):

Your question is broad. More than likely yes. That microcontroller seems to be there for USB connectivity only. In the end, that microcontroller communicates with the FPGA over UART, SPI or something else and in an FPGA those can be any pins.

Comment: there seems to be more than the microcontroller providing usb interface. 1) it flashes the fpga every time it boots. 2) after it boots, it enter into slave mode, making it effectively just like any general purpose microcontroller from thereon, instead of being just a flashing-booting device 3) as for providing the usb, it ALSO provides an interface for updating the rom that the microcontroller itself will flash into the fpga, eliminating the jtag. as for the #3, i don't know if it happens before booting or after it becomes a slave.